# Select list showing limited contacts, using “CiviCRM Contact” reference in drupal

Tags: drupal, contact-reference

I'm having problem while storing values in select list field, for this field i'm using "CiviCRM Contact" reference. I have more than 30,000 contacts, but why in select list showing limited contacts? its showing maximum 10 contacts.

( Note : I have set "Number of values" : "Unlimited" for select list )

Answer (score 2):

I see there is a limit set while building the options on the select list. It seems this has been only handled for `autocomplete` widget as `$limit` doesn't gets modified anywhere in the function or is nowhere passed to `_civicrm_contact_ref_potential_references_standard()` function.

So, it is set to a default value of 10 every time the list is loaded irrespective of the widget used.